# What tools/IDE/languages exists for generating C-code

Tags: c, compiler-construction, code-generation

I wanted to know more about tools that assist in writing code-generators for C. Essentially how do we achieve functionality similar to c++ templates.

Comment: I think you have to be more specific with what you want to achieve.

Comment: I agree. Just had too little information about the topic and I am not too sure what I am asking for. I will try again. I have a code that works for a given data-type in C, lets say integers. I want to generalise this to other data-types. I don't think simply doing typedef and search-replace would work. Is there tool and more well defined approach of performing code generation.  In other I want exactly the template features but don't mind doing two step compilation. My target language is C.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is to use the extension built into C called "C++".

Comment: I have gone through the obvious route. I enjoyed it and learned a lot. I felt it hampered my productivity and looking for not-so-powerful non-obvious solution.

Comment: If you have boilerplate code for an algorithm, and can't use templates, then some kind of macro processor makes sense.  You also will want to put conditions *into* the macro, so C macros won't work.  The M4 suggestion will let you do all this.

Comment: Thanks Ira,  I do believe so. Although I am not sure if m4 is good payoff for the complexity since it may not provide verifications and semantics checking as a C++ would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's not a perfect solution and it takes some time to master it, I've used the [m4 macro processor](http://www.gnu.org/s/m4/) in the past for generic C code generation (kinda like C++ templates). You may want to check that out.

Comment: I'm pretty certain m4 macros are not "like C++ templates". Try writing `type_traits` or `Boost::Spirit` with both, or for that matter, doing *any* nontrivial template metaprogramming.

Comment: Well, since GNU m4 is Turing complete, in theory you can do something equivalent to `type_traits` or `Boost:Spirit`. I recon that it wouldn't be practically feasible though. Still, m4 works well for simpler things like simple generic containers in my opinion.

Comment: Granted, it may work for duplicating the source code for some containers or algorithms and replacing a few pieces to "instanciate" them (some preprocessor hackery should work equally well). But that's only a tiny subset of C++ templates. Please don't reduce them to that (and please don't go the stupid turing tarpit route - nobody cares you can, given infinite time and unyielding code monkeys, people only care if you can in reasonable time with reasonable resources).

Comment: I know that C++ templates are very powerful. What I'm trying to say is that if, for some reason, you don't have the option to use C++ (in my case the reason was that no C++ compilers were available for the target system), but you desperately need a limited kind of generic programming to avoid massive code duplication, m4 works fine. And it works way better than C preprocessor in my experience.

Comment: Thanks cyco. m4 might just work for me. Would have loved something simpler or compiler-oriented. BUt I agree that simple task m4 may be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to generate code for very similar classes, where what differs is essentially their type.

You can use a template-based code generator, where "template" means "boilerplate code" with string substitution. This is the simplest scenario. A tool like [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org) or CodeSmith will do the job. But there are many others. Just search around.

If you want a more serious generation scenario, where different class structures might be needed according to a set of definitions, then you should go with a fully programmable generator like [AtomWeaver](http://www.atomweaver.com). There are others (MPS, Xtext) but these do not rely on templates.

Comment: Thanks Rui. I will give it a try. Not sure how it will generate C code though?

Comment: AtomWeaver is an IDE, much like MS Visual Studio, but for code generation. To generate code, create an Atom Template, and in the Exec section of the Template, enclose your code using the code() command. Create parameters on your template and replace variable parts of your code with these parameters. Anyway, you should run the tutorials for some simple examples...